# Read Webpage With User IP Address in php

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I want to make a a script that processes a web-page and returns some variables on that page to user! but I want to open that page with user's ip because that page returns information special for every ip address so I can not use curl and etc.
in the other words I want to see a page that a user with his ip will see!!
I think a could use a iframe to open that page and use some Javascript to upload that html page to server.
any body have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Question is absolutely not clear. Please explain how do you want to process the page and what do you mean with "open with user ip".
You mean that you want to scrap the page HTML and retrieve data as if it were a certain (and variable) IP making the connection?

Comment: Upto my understanding, check out my answer, is that what you are trying out @Hossein?

Comment: yes actually. I want to open a page as if a certain user (current user) opens that page.

Comment: No, you can't spoof the user's IP address from your server. TCP's 3-way handshake makes that impossible. You'd have to use javascript in the client's browser for this, and most like you'd run into cross-domain security restrictions anyways.

Comment: In general, you can't "fake" the IP address that the server receives.

Comment: I removed the JSP tag since JSP isn't JavaScript. (I'm assuming you mean JavaScript - please correct me if I'm wrong.) Also, you will probably encounter the cross-domain policy here.

Comment: @ScottS: if you think so it's true! because I'm a beginner to javascript! actually what's their difference? :)<br>
actually I want to open a page in a iframe in my domain and display user-name and some other data of user that displayed somewhere on that page offside of that iframe!<br>
can you help me where to start to learn JavaScript to do that?<br>
thank you!!

Comment: @Hossein [JSP:Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) & [JavaScript:Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). Java Server Pages, are, naturally, server side (like PHP). You need the client to request the page; you need client side (Javascript). I will elaborate later, sorry I'm late & I have to go.

Comment: @Hossein you may be interested in the [Cross-Domain/Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), I think this is going to make your attempts very difficult (assuming this is not your site that you are trying to fetch from). I don't like being the bearer of bad news, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php server variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the users IP address.

You can use that to do the rest of the processing that you want.

Comment: thank you. but don't want to return a user's ip address. I want to open a web-page and see every thing that a sample user with his ip will see!

Comment: That is easy, have some parameter that tells php not to use the users ip address but use one that you provide. If that is set, use that instead of the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Something like: myPage.php?viewAs=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` it returns the IP Address of the visitor.

If you wanna do something like IP Address based chat, you can save the IP Address in the MySQL Table and based on that, display the messages. :)

For eg, this code I guess does what you want:

```
<?php echo "Hi User! Please open your IP Address @ {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}"; ?>
```

This displays for me as:

```
Hi User! Please open your IP Address @ 122.164.125.224
```

And for you as:

```
Hi User! Please open your IP Address @ 127.0.0.1
```

Is this what you are trying out?

In your case, for a user to see that way, have a list of IP Addresses, and based on that process the output:

```
<?php
    $specialips = array('127.0.0.1', '122.164.122.164', '10.0.0.52');
    if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $specialips))
        echo 'Welcome Special User!';
    else
        echo 'Hello Normal User!';
?>
```

Comment: thank you. but don't want to return a user's ip address. I want to open a web-page and see every thing that a sample user with his ip will see!

Comment: Check out now. Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, but I think you misunderstand me! I want to open a page for a user like a proxy server, and process its data and return some data to user. at first I assumed to open page with server using curl and etc but that page returns data special for every ip address so I cannot open that page with server because in that way information will be returned for server's ip address!

Comment: In that case, it is not possible, when you say that you are gonna do like a proxy server, then only your server's IP address will be sent out. But you can do one thing. Check out Squid Proxy server's source code and why don't you implement some kind of users and privileges concept?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. Any request you make using it will come from the server's IP. You can use something like Javascript, and pass the result to PHP, but PHP itself can't directly make the request.

Comment: thank you for your replay!
but I'm familiar with jsp very much. I think that maybe there is way to open that page in a iframe and read it and send it to server! is that the correct way to do that?
thank you!!
I can only do this with jsp? if yes can you help me to do that?

Comment: I guess you can do with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`!

Comment: Yes, you could load it in an iframe then read the contents with Javascript (not JSP) and send it to a PHP script on your server.

Comment: thank you. but I'm beginner with jsp! can you help me to from where I start to learn that and so I could do that?
thank you

Comment: JavaScript is not the same as JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to spoof an IP address. That is not typically possible, since IP addresses are validated through a three-way TCP handshake, and the response will be sent to that verified IP. To spoof IP addresses you need at least an elevated network position, which you typically don't have.

Comment: thank you. I think I can to that by loading page to a iframe and send information from from there to server using jsp.
but I don't know lot about jsp. any idea how to to that?

Comment: I don't know what JSP has to do with that. If you can get the user to open your page, which has an iframe to another page, the user would see that page from his IP. You may be able to do something using Javascript in the browser, but this will probably fail due to same-origin policy restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky you can fake the IP via [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) headers you inject. Probably that other script is that dumb to fall on this (as most scripts do).

Please consult the documentation of the HTTP layer you use (PHP, curl, etc.) how you can specify request headers.